# stream creating List of List (nested List) using forEach, Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, nested-lists

```
class EntityCompositeId {
    private Long firstId;
    private Long secondId;
    // getter & setter...
}

class EntityComposite {
    private EntityCompositeId id;
    private String first;
    private String second;
    // getter & setter...
}

List<EntityComposite> listEntityComposite = ....
Supose this content

1, 1, "firstA", "secondBirdOne"
1, 2, "firstA", "secondBirdTwo"
1, 3, "firstA", "secondBirdThree"

2, 1, "firstB", "secondCatOne"
2, 2, "firstB", "secondCatTwo"
2, 3, "firstB", "secondCatThree"

3, 1, "firstC", "secondDogOne"
3, 2, "firstC", "secondDogTwo"
3, 3, "firstC", "secondDogThree"

Map<Long, List<String>> listOfLists = new HashMap<>();
```

Now using stream I want to fill like:

```
 1 -> {"secondBirdOne", "secondBirdTwo", "secondBirdThree"}
 2 -> {"secondCatOne", "secondCatTwo", "secondCatThree"}
 3 -> {"secondDogOne", "secondDogTwo", "secondDogThree"}
```

My UNFINISHED (that's the question) code is:

```
listEntityComposite.stream()forEach(entityComposite {
        // How create a list according entityComposite.getId.getFirstId()?
        listOfLists.put(entityComposite.getId.getFirstId(), .... )
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several different approaches in which you can accomplish the task at hand.

## forEach + computeIfAbsent

```
 Map<Long, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
 listEntityComposite.forEach(e -> map.computeIfAbsent(e.getId().getFirstId(), 
                k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(e.getSecond()));
```

- enumerates over the elements in `listEntityComposite` via `forEach`
- for each element utilises `computeIfAbsent` to compute the key (i.e. `firstId`) and value (i.e. `List<String>`)

## groupingBy + mapping

another approach would be to apply a `groupingBy` with a `mapping` downstream collector:

```
Map<Long, List<String>> resultSet = listEntityComposite.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getId().getFirstId(),
                        mapping(EntityComposite::getSecond, toList())));
```

- groups the source elements by the classification function `e.getId().getFirstId()` and then applies a `mapping` downstream collector to further refine our query.

## forEach + merge

```
listEntityComposite.forEach(e -> map.merge(e.getId().getFirstId(),
                new ArrayList<>(singletonList(e.getSecond())),
                (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}));
```

- enumerates over the elements in `listEntityComposite` via `forEach`
- for each element utilises `merge` to compute the key (i.e. `firstId`) and value (i.e. `List<String>`)

## toMap

```
listEntityComposite.stream()
                   .collect(toMap(e -> e.getId().getFirstId(), 
                             v ->  new ArrayList<>(singletonList(v.getSecond())),
                             (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}));
```

- applies a `keyMapper` function `e -> e.getId().getFirstId()` to extract the map keys.
- applies a `valueMapper` function `v ->  new ArrayList<>(singletonList(v.getSecond()))` to extract the map values.
- applies a `merge` function `(l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}` to resolve key collisions.

To conclude, the `forEach` + `computeIfAbsent` approach and the `groupingBy` + `mapping` approach are the two you should favour in this specific case as they're the more idiomatic.

Answer (score 10):

`collect` is a more suitable terminal operation for generating an output `Map` than `forEach`.

You can use `collect()` with `Collectors.groupingBy`:

```
Map<Long, List<String>> listOfLists =
    listEntityComposite.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getId().getFirstId(),
                                                      Collectors.mapping(EntityComposite::getSecond,
                                                                         Collectors.toList());
```

`Collectors.groupingBy` with a single argument (just `e -> e.getId().getFirstId()`) would generate a `Map<Long,List<EntityComposite>>`.

Chaining to it `Collectors.mapping()` maps each `EntityComposite` instance to the corresponding `getSecond()` `String`, as required.

Comment: Sorry, what about of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844376

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Guava's MultiMap which makes your use-case easier to deal with (providing lots of optimizations and extra functionality you may want to obtain later down the road)

Edit:
An example of why Multimap makes more sense than, say, using the computeIfAbsent approach:
 1. each key has a list of a certain size, what if you'll want to get the "total" size in the future? you would have to create some logic to achieve this with good performance (or use a method that takes O(keys))
 2. at the moment you're only putting things into the map, but what happens if you want to remove things from the map in the future? You will need to write some boilerplate code (that is easy to get wrong) to make sure that removing values doesn't cause a memory leak

There are other things to gain from using a multimap but these are just two easy to explain benefits.

Edit 2:
An example using your input:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap;

public class Example {

    public static class EntityCompositeId {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EntityCompositeId [firstId=" + firstId + ", secondId=" + secondId + "]";
        }

        public EntityCompositeId(Long firstId, Long secondId) {
            super();
            this.firstId = firstId;
            this.secondId = secondId;
        }

        private Long firstId;

        public Long getFirstId() {
            return firstId;
        }

        private Long secondId;
    }

    public static class EntityComposite {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EntityComposite [id=" + id + ", first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";
        }

        public EntityComposite(EntityCompositeId id, String first, String second) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        private EntityCompositeId id;

        public EntityCompositeId getId() {
            return id;
        }

        private String first;
        private String second;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<EntityComposite> listEntityComposite = Arrays.asList(
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(1l, 1l), "firstA", "secondBirdOne"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(1l, 2l), "firstA", "secondBirdTwo"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(1l, 3l), "firstA", "secondBirdThree"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(2l, 1l), "firstB", "secondCatOne"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(2l, 2l), "firstB", "secondCatTwo"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(2l, 3l), "firstB", "secondCatThree"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(3l, 1l), "firstC", "secondDogOne"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(3l, 2l), "firstC", "secondDogTwo"),
                new EntityComposite(new EntityCompositeId(3l, 3l), "firstC", "secondDogThree"));
        ListMultimap<Long, EntityComposite> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        listEntityComposite.forEach(entityComposite -> map.put(entityComposite.getId().getFirstId(), entityComposite));
        map.keySet().forEach(key -> System.out.println(map.get(key)));
    }
}
```

Yields the following output:

```
[EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=1, secondId=1], first=firstA, second=secondBirdOne], EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=1, secondId=2], first=firstA, second=secondBirdTwo], EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=1, secondId=3], first=firstA, second=secondBirdThree]]
[EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=2, secondId=1], first=firstB, second=secondCatOne], EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=2, secondId=2], first=firstB, second=secondCatTwo], EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=2, secondId=3], first=firstB, second=secondCatThree]]
[EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=3, secondId=1], first=firstC, second=secondDogOne], EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=3, secondId=2], first=firstC, second=secondDogTwo], EntityComposite [id=EntityCompositeId [firstId=3, secondId=3], first=firstC, second=secondDogThree]]
```