# creating nested maps with nested properties from List, stream, Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, nested-properties, nested-map

I made this question 
[stream creating List of List (nested List) using forEach, Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53786325/811293)

```
class EntityCompositeId {
    private Long firstId;
    private Long secondId;
    // getter & setter...
}

class EntityComposite {
    private EntityCompositeId id;
    private String first;
    private String second;
    // getter & setter...
}

List<EntityComposite> listEntityComposite = ....
Supose this content

1, 1, "firstA", "secondBirdOne"
1, 2, "firstA", "secondBirdTwo"
1, 3, "firstA", "secondBirdThree"

2, 1, "firstB", "secondCatOne"
2, 2, "firstB", "secondCatTwo"
2, 3, "firstB", "secondCatThree"

3, 1, "firstC", "secondDogOne"
3, 2, "firstC", "secondDogTwo"
3, 3, "firstC", "secondDogThree"

Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> listOfLists = new HashMap<>();
```

Now using stream I want to fill like:

```
 1 -> {1 ->"secondBirdOne", 2 -> "secondBirdTwo", 3 -> "secondBirdThree"}
 2 -> {1 ->"secondCatOne", 2 -> "secondCatTwo", 3 -> "secondCatThree"}
 3 -> {1 ->"secondDogOne", 2 -> "secondDogTwo", 3 -> "secondDogThree"}
```

My NOT functional code was:

```
    Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> listaMunDepa = listEntityComposite.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> e.getId().getFirstId(),
            Collectors.toMap(f -> f.getId().getSecondId(), Function.identity()))
    );
```

second Try

```
    Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> listaMunDepa = listEntityComposite.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> e.getId().getFirstId(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(EntityComposite::getId::getSecondId, EntityComposite::getSecond)) // How change this line
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're *really close*, instead of passing `Function.identity`, you should pass `EntityComposite::getSecond`

```
listEntityComposite.stream()
           .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getId().getFirstId(),
                  toMap(f -> f.getId().getSecondId(), EntityComposite::getSecond)));
```

because you supplied `Function.identity` the result was `Map<Long, Map<Long, EntityComposite>>`, so as shown above, you'll simply need to extract the `getSecondId` for the `valueMapper` function supplied to `toMap` hence yielding a `Map<Long, Map<Long, String>>`.

Comment: Sorry, what about of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844376, thanks.